# Distinct Row Templates for NSPredicateEditor/NSRuleEditor rows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use different row templates for specific rows in an NSPredicateEditor (or, if need be, an NSRuleEditor). I've got a screenshot that I think helps me explain this more clearly.
[image: NSPredicateEditor example screenshot]

In this contrived example, I only want people to generate a filter that looks for a specific path above a certain size. So, in Section A (the Any block), users can only specify path rules (and the users can add additional paths). In section B, I only want the Size option to be available.

Nothing's jumping out at me from the docs (or, the stuff that does jump out at me ends up being something else), but it seems like this is the sort of thing that might come in handy, which makes me think it might be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand about `NSPredicateEditor`, this is not possible.  You might be able to swing it if you do everything yourself with an `NSRuleEditor`, but I haven't played with that class as much.

So in a nutshell: if you implement it yourself, it's possible.  With the built-in stuff, I'm 99.9% certain that it's not a configurable behavior.

Comment: Looks like that's the case. I've got to say, finding anything about implementing `NSRuleEditor` is a royal pain. I ended up finding a sample project on the Mac Rumors forums (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=948727), of all places.